# Fusion Drive is split and not available for repartitioning

Tags: imac, bootcamp, partition

I'm using an iMac 5k Retina 2014 (old, I know) with OSX Yosemite installed. For some reason Bootcamp has never worked with my USB drives, so I tried manually installing Windows 10.

I partitioned the internal drive in Disk Utility, put all the necessary files on my USB, and booted into Windows. I went through the installation process and it asked what drive I wanted to install on, so I selected the new partition I just made, deleted it, clicked new then format, and went on with installing.

The installation failed and when I checked  Disk Utility again, the Fusion Drive is only showing 1.67TB of space opposed to the full 3TB. There's a smaller disk image that I assume Windows created, along with the remaining 1.33TB of free space that I can't restore to the Fusion Drive.

I've tried using Terminal commands but can't for my life figure out what to put in because my `diskutil` list is so long. Any help would be great.
[image: list]

Comment: At a minimum you do need to show the output of `diskutil list` (you could remove any repeating similar sections). I have never done it, but my understanding is that bootcamp on a Fusion Drive is VERY tricky - only attempt once you have a good backup of the Mac.

Comment: rantey: The Fusion Drive does not appear to be split. If you are trying to install Windows, I would think you would be better off fixing your partitioning problems by using `diskpart`. Here I assume you want Windows to occupy about 1.2 TB of space.

Comment: @DavidAnderson So for some reason the remaining 1.2TB of space doesn't come up on the list, but in disk utility it's shown as free space that can't be rejoined with the fusion drive. I'm helpless with terminal commands so if you have any idea what I should input that would be great.

Comment: You probably should add to your question the output from the command `sudo gpt -r show disk9`. Note: You might not need the `sudo`. The identifier should be for the drive containing the `Microsoft Reserved` partition. In the image you posted, this was `disk9`. If the identifier has changed, make the appropriate substitution.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Said it was "unable to open disk9: resource busy" ???

Comment: The identifier may not be `disk9`. When you look at the output from `diskutil list`, is `disk9` the drive with the `Microsoft Reserved` partition?